# copying to and from hdfs within Hadoop Streaming

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I asked a similar question to this earlier, but after doing some exploring, I have a better understanding of what's going on, but i'd like to see if other people have alternative solutions to my approach.

### Problem

Suppose you're trying to write a Hadoop streaming job that gzips a bunch of really large files on hdfs.  [The Hadoop Streaming guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.15.2/streaming.html#How+do+I+process+files%2C+one+per+map%3F)  suggests that you write a mapper to copy the file from hdfs onto the local node, do your work, then copy the file back to hdfs.  Here's a small script, with some extra code tthat's explained inline, to doa slightly more basic task: simply rename some file

#### The Script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remove "s from the environment variable to work around a stupid bug in hadoop.
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS=`echo $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS | tr -d '"'`

# Get just the size of the file on the local disk.
function localSize() {
 ls -l $1 | awk '{ print $5 }'
}

# Get just the size of the file on HDFS.  Oddly, the first command includes a 
# new line at the start of the size, so we remove it by using a substring.
function hdfsSize() {
 s=`hadoop dfs -ls /some/other/path/$1 | awk '{ print $5 }'`
 echo ${s:1}
}

while read line
do
 ds=ourFile.dat
 # Copy the file from HDFS to local disk.
 hadoop dfs -copyToLocal /path/to/some/large/file/$ds $ds
 # Spin until the file is fully copied.
 while [ ! -f $ds ]
 do 
  echo "spin"
  sleep 1 
 done

 # Delete the renamed version of the file and copy it.
 hadoop dfs -rm /some/other/path/blah
 hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal $ds /some/other/path/blah
 # Print out the sizes of the file on local disk and hdfs, they *should* be equal
 localSize $ds
 hdfsSize blah
 # If they aren't equal, spin until they are.
 while [ "`localSize $ds`" != "`hdfsSize blah`" ]
 do
  echo "copy spin"
  sleep 1
 done
 # Print out the file size at the end, just for fun.
 hadoop dfs -ls /some/other/path/blah
done
```

#### Output

After running the script, we get this output

```
spin
spin
spin
Deleted hdfs://kracken:54310/some/other/path/blah
200890778
67108864
copy spin
Found 1 items   
-rw-r--r--   3 hadoop supergroup  200890778 2011-10-06 16:00 /home/stevens35/blah
```

#### The Issue

It seems clear that `hadoop dfs -copyToLocal` and `hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal` seem to be returning before the relevant files have finished transfering, as seen by the `spin` and `copy spin` outputs.  My guess is that the Hadoop streaming jvm is adopting the thread created by the `hadoop dfs` command and so the file transfer threads keep running even though `hadoop dfs` exits, but this is just a guess.  This becomes particularly annoying when the file is large, and Hadoop streaming exits before the last file is finished copying; it seems as if the file transfer dies midway through and you're left with a paritial file on HDFS.  This hack of mine seems to at least ensure that the files finish copying.

I should note that I'm using Cloudera's hadoop version 0.20.2+737.

Has anyone encountered this problem? What alternative work arounds have you found? And has the issue been fixed in any newer releaeses of Hadoop?

Comment: I have seen a similar query in stackoverflow of incomplete file using copyToLocal in streaming, but couldn't find it. It seems to be a bug in the Hadoop. Ask the same question in mapreduce-dev@hadoop.apache.org and file a JIRA if required. I have seen the [code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java) and the copyToLocal seems to be a synchronous call only. Also, OutputStream.flush() is not explicitly called, not sure if flush() is called automatically in close(). Let us know the solution.

Comment: That similar query was mine, but i deleted it so that i could write this one in more detail without having a duplicate query :)  I do plan on filing a ticket, but I wanted to leave this here in part so that other people here know of the issue and see a work around, and to see if others here have tried anything.

Comment: I haven't seen much activity/eyes around Hadoop here in SO, so it's better to send it to mapreduce-dev and file a JIRA if it's really a bug.

Comment: Implementation of the copyToLocal looks completely synchronious. May be it is local file system caching issues? What is your OS, Local fs?